# How exactly is a Field monomorphism defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, field-theory, monomorphisms

Multiple times in my question I'll use the term 'a mapping of $x$', what I mean with this is one of the element to which $x$ can be mapped to (since there could be more than one).

We have Two fields, $L$ and $K$, which operators are $+$ and $×$. A field monomorphism $α:K→L$ would be a homorphism, that is, a mapping that suffices the properties

$$α(x+y)=α(x)+α(y)$$

$$α(x×y)=α(x)×α(y)$$,

and is injective, that is, it never maps two different elements in $K$ to the same element in $L$. However, the possibility is open for an injective mapping to map the same element in $K$ to two, or more, different elements in $L$. This is what is confusing me.

---

Multiple times in my question I'll use the term 'a mapping of $x$', I refer with this phrase to one of the element to which $x$ is be mapped to by $α$ (since there could be more than one).

---

Imagine that $α$ maps $x$ to $r_1$ and $r_2$, and maps $y$ to $s_1$ and $s_2$. Then, by definition,

$$α(x+y)=α(x)+α(y)$$,

but what does this exactly mean? Does it mean that for whichever mapping of $x$ and $y$ we pick, $α(x+y)$ must equal their sum, in the sense that $(x+y)$ would be mapped, at the very least to $(r_1+s_1), (r_1+s_2), (r_2+s_1)$ and $(r_2+s_2)$?

Or does it mean that for each mapping of $x$, there has to be at least one mapping of $y$ such that $α(x+y)=α(x)+α(y)$, in the sense that $(x+y)$ would be mapped at the very least to $(r_1+s_1)$ and $(r_2+s_2)$?

Or, my last interpretation, does it mean that there has to exists at least one mapping of $x$ and one mapping of $y$ such that $α(x+y)=α(x)+α(y)$, in the sense that $(x+y)$ would be mapped to at least $r_1+s_1$?

---

Which one is the correct interpretation? If nine of the interpretations I gave is correct, what would be the proper one?

I would really appreciate any help/thoughts!

Comment: But $\alpha$ is a function so there is a unique $\alpha(x)$, there *can't* be multiple ones

Comment: You should probably review what a function is before embarking on studying the theory of fields.

Comment: May I ask you how and where you are educated? This is not meant derogatory, I’m just genuinely perplexed by the fact that you do seem to have grasped the notions of injectivity, fields and homomorphisms, but apparently have missed the basic definition of a *map*.

Comment: But doesn't an I injective mapping leave open the possibility of mapping one two elements of its domain to the same element of its range? I'm I wrong about this?

Comment: I'm a freshman in college, but all the abstract algebra I study I do it by myself.

Comment: Look up the definition of a map. If $f \colon X → Y$ is a map of sets $X$, $Y$, then $$“x = x’ \implies f(x) = f(x').”$$ This is a *requirement* for being a map. Being injective means that, *in addition to that*, $$“x = x' \Longleftarrow f(x) = f(x').”$$ Field homomorphisms are *defined* to be maps with the properties you listed, and then turn out to be always injective anyway.

Comment: "But doesn't an I injective mapping leave open the possibility of mapping one two elements of its domain to the same element of its range?"  No, the definition of an injective function is a function where this doesn't happen.

Comment: As an aside, in general "monomorphism" is not a synonym for "injective". However, it turns out they mean the same thing for field homomorphisms.

Answer (score 1):

All field homomorphisms are monomorphisms.

All fields are rings, and we have that the kernel of any ring-homomorphsim is an ideal of the domain ring (verify this!).

If a ring ideal (of a ring $R$) $I$, contains a unit, say $u$, then $I = R$, because for any $r \in R$, we have $r = (ru^{-1})u \in I$.

It follows that if $R$ is a field, there are only two possible ideals: $R$ and $(0)$.

If $R=F$, a field, then any ring-homomorphism $\phi:F \to E$ image is thus:

$F/F \cong\{0\}$, or $\phi(F) \cong F/(0) \cong F$.

The first possibility cannot be a field-homomorphism, because in a field $0 \neq 1$, and the image is not a field, because it lacks a multiplicative identity distinct from $0$.

The second (and thus only) possibility is a monomorphism, because it has kernel $0$.

(In fact, the above argument can be extended to *division-rings*, which shows all division-ring homomorphisms are also monomorphisms. The condition that all non-zero elements are units, is thus *very* restrictive on what kind of ring-homomorphisms are possible, which essentially means the study of division-ring and field morphisms boils down to the concept of extensions, which serve as the main topic of investigation).

---

As others have commented above, it cannot happen for a function $f$ to have two distinct images $f(x)_1$ and $f(x)_2$-such a *relation* is called an *ill-defined* function, for then $f(x)$ is unclear as an *element* of the co-domain, although it may make sense as a *set*.

Since homomorphisms are *required* to be (well-defined) functions, the behavior you are concerned about cannot happen. This becomes *particularly* important when studying *quotient objects*, because a map (in rings, for example) $R \to R/I$:

$a \mapsto a+I$ has to be unambiguous, no matter which pre-image of the set $a+I$ we pick.

One of the consequences of this is that "quotient fields" are for all intents and purposes, nonexistent.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, unless stated otherwise, the term "mapping" (or "map", or "function") refers to a *single-valued* operation.  In other words, if $f:X\to Y$ is a mapping, for each $x\in X$ there is *exactly one* value $f(x)\in Y$.  More formally, you can think of $f$ as being given by a set  $S$ of ordered pairs $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ such that for each $x\in X$ there is exactly one $y$ such that $(x,y)\in S$.  We then write $f(x)$ for the unique $y$ such that $(x,y)\in S$.

So, your $\alpha$ always maps any $x\in K$ to exactly one element of $L$, and there is no ambiguity of the sort you are asking about.